# Problema en terminal de vscode

Tags: javascript, vscode, terminal

```
{
  "name": "Alkemy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.2",
    "express-mysql-session": "^2.1.7",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "passport": "^0.5.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "timeago.js": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\laura\OneDrive\Escritorio\Alkemy\src'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Comment: ¿Puedes aportar más datos? el fichero Package.json vendría bien para poder resolver.

Comment: Mis disculpas. Ya modifiqué la pregunta